# Insertar registros en mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando un sistema de registro de usuarios y una de las funciones es crear una base de datos e insertarle registros en unas tabla para los cual cree una clase que hace lo siguiente:

Crear la base de datos:

```
$create_db = $this->pdo->prepare('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS '.$dataBaseName.' COLLATE utf8_general_ci');                              
        $crear_db->execute();
```

usar la base de datos creada

```
if($create_db):
    $use_db = $this->pdo->prepare('USE '.$dataBaseName);                          
    $use_db->execute();
endif;
```

crear la tablas, para esto tomo una base de datos de referencia y creo las tablas asi:

```
            $create_table = $this->pdo->prepare('
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account_daily LIKE db_ref.account_daily; 
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account_plan LIKE db_ref.account_plan; 
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS branch LIKE db_ref.branch; 
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cash_register LIKE db_ref.cash_register; 
            ');                         
            $create_table->execute();
```

Enseguida debe insertar algunos registros en varias tablas, para esto utilizo la siguiente instruccion

```
//primera tabla    
$sql = "INSERT INTO account_plan (`acc_id`, `acc_number`, `acc_account`, `acc_class`, `acc_group`, `acc_active`, `acc_balance`) VALUES
        (1, '1105', 'Caja', 'Activo', 'Activo - Disponible', 1, '0.00'),
        //y asi otros registros
    $insert_data = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);   
    $insert_data->execute();";

//segunda tabla
            $sql = "INSERT INTO type_grp (`typ_id`, `typ_active`, `typ_name`) VALUES
                (1, 1, 'Inventario'),
                (2, 1, 'Insumos'),
                (3, 1, 'Servicios');";
            $insert_data = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);   
            $insert_data->execute();

//tercera tabla etc...
```

El problema esta en que en la primera tabla no se graban lo registros pero en la segunda, terecera y demas SI, es decir desde el segundo `insert`.

He optado por hacer un `insert` antes del `insert` en la primera tabla y asi si se graba la primera tabla.

Me funciona bien pero me gustaria saber por que pasa esto y cual seria la solucion correcta. Gracias

Comment: Seria bueno que añadieras un manejo de errores para ver qué pasa. Puedes probar con esto `if (!($insert_data = $this->pdo->prepare($sql))) { echo "Error: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error; }`. Lo mismo para el `execute()`.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cuál es el problema. No obstante en el contexto que describes, puedes evitar el `USE database` y agregar a tus consultas el nombre de la base de datos, dando por supuesto que el usuario que tiene la conexión tiene privilegios también para esa base de datos. Sería cuestión de escribir tus consultas así: `"INSERT INTO $dataBaseName.AquíTuTabla ..."`. Otra cosa, aunque no es motivo de error: no uses `prepare` de forma indiscriminada. Muchas de tus consultas no necesitan ser preparadas, porque no suponen riesgo de inyección. Si no vas a reutilizarlas usa `query` en ese caso.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios!